# How to use the url that came in response

Tags: python-2.7, tdd, robotframework

Help to understand and direct what needs to be done further. I use the robot framework version 3.1.1 and the Python 2.7 programming language to write the autotest script, and now there is a task to develop a test that will work with POST / GET requests. So, I make a POST request to the system to initiate a payment. The answer comes that the payment has been created, but for all actions it is necessary to follow the link inside the answer.

Request:

```
Create Session    allias    URL
&{params}=    Create Dictionary    params1=value1  params2=value2  
${resp}=    Post Request    allias    /init_payment.php    params=${params}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```

Reply post response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response><pg_status>ok</pg_status><pg_payment_id>3016695</pg_payment_id><pg_redirect_url>https://test.paybox.money/payment.html?customer=028c44bf25b6be251199221d04b570c2</pg_redirect_url><pg_redirect_url_type>need data</pg_redirect_url_type><pg_salt>8OYUsodtnaTWKbOD</pg_salt><pg_sig>a26e61d6eb710c430d67150498d1f555</pg_sig></response>
```

How to show the framework so that it can go through the redirect url? I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RequestsKeywors from the Robot Framework use [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) HTTP Client. Reading the [quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) from this library you can find that the response's contents is available in the `text` field.

```
${body}=    ${resp.text}
```

Then you'd most likely want to parse the XML. You can use the [XML library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) for that.

It will be something like

```
${root} =   Parse XML   ${body}
${link} =   Get Element Text    ${root} response/pg_redirect_url
```

Comment: When searching for an item in the response text. I get the error: ***ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 9***

Comment: Colleagues, please help with the question. Why the following is returned when parsing XML: Element 'response' at 0x044FD5A8.
I understand that the Robot Framework returns an object to me, but why do I need an object? How do I search for the desired value?

Comment: `Parse` returns the root element of the XML as an object. You search for desired value with `Get Element Text`, which takes this object as the first argument and xpath to the element as the second one. I guess that in this case you don't need to repeat the reponse tag, so the second line would be:
`${link} =   Get Element Text    ${root} response/pg_redirect_url`